# JS - Multidimensional Array and Match 3 system

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I make a matched-3 game in Unity (I use **UnityScript** (Javascript for Unity)), based on Tetris gameplay (cubes are dropped like Tetris to create row & columns of colored cubes), and I need to find a way to Check if there is 3 colored cubes in a row (or column).

The game logic is actually very simple, but I have a problem with Cubes Comparison.

### 1. Storing the values

**I create a multi dimensional Array, and I push Values for every Cube, by using a Loop :**

```
    cells[0, 0] // this is the Cube n°0, and it's X Position
    cells[0, 1] // this is the Cube n°0, and it's Y Position
    cells[0, 2] // this is the Cube n°0, and it's ID
    cells[0, 3] // this is the Cube n°0, and it's Color

    cells[1, 0] // this is the Cube n°1, and it's X Position
    cells[1, 1] // this is the Cube n°1, and it's Y Position
    cells[1, 2] // this is the Cube n°1, and it's ID
    cells[1, 3] // this is the Cube n°1, and it's Color
…

// etc…
```

So, if I want the **X Pos.** of my **Cube 1**, I juste have to Call "**cells[0, 0];**". *This works perfectly fine.*

### 2. The Matching 3 Logic

**The logic to find a 3 cubes Vertical match is simple (it is in a "for" loop that "scan" all the Cubes):**

```
if ( cells[row,cell] == cells[row,cell+1] == cells[row,cell+2] ) // The Problem is here, see my question below
{
    print("Congrats, you have stacked 3 cubes in a column !");
    // + Here I add my function to Destroy cubes and Collapse row(s)/col(s)
}
```

As you can see in my script, the line : "if ( cells[row,cell] == cells[row,cell+1] == cells[row,cell+2] )" is the problem.

What I (really) want to do:

**if "CELL_A with Y position = 3"** is equal to **"CELL_B with Y position = 2 + 1"** is equal to **"CELL_C with Y position = 1 + 2"**, then it's a match.

### 3. The problem

So, I can perfectly search for Vertical Cubes with the "for" loop, but my problem is in the line: "**cells[row,cell] == cells[row,cell+1] == cells[row,cell+2]**".

Since if I wan't "**cell+1**" to be "***The Cell Pos Y value + 1***", the loop don't find that value, but the next Value stored in the Array : **Y Position**, or **CubeID**, or **Color ID**…

Because **if cell = 1**, and I wan't "**cell+2**", cell+2 = **cells[0, 2]**, so the result is: "**the Cube n°0, and it's ID**".

### 4. The Question

How can I add a value to the **Second int** of **Cells** Array ?

Instead of:

**cells[0, (1+1)]** = Cube ID ( because result is: cells[0, 2] )

I want:

**cells[0, (1+1)]** = the **value** "Cube 0: Y Position" **+1**

---

So:

When I search for "**if ( cells[row,cell+1] == 1 )**", I find the **cube** who has the number **1** as *Pos Y Value*.

I hope my explanation is good enough, if you need more details let me know. Thanks in advance for your help, and sorry for my poor english.

---

PS: If you have any other algorithm in mind who could do the job, I would totally take it gladly ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to see if all three are equal to one value you can try this:

```
if ( (cells[row,cell] & cells[row, (cell+1)] & cells[row,(cell+2)]) == "some value" )
```

Unless you are looping over rows and then columns across you should be able to check the same columns against each other. So cells[row, 0] & cell[row, 1]. You should only need a variable for the column if you are for some reason looping across at the same time you are looping down over rows.

```
if ( (cells[row,0] & cells[row, 1] & cells[row,2]) == "some value" )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I believe that Unity does not treat arrays that way. (http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Which_Kind_Of_Array_Or_Collection_Should_I_Use?#2D_Array). And when I make a test, I have no problem to read the Value by using "print(cells[1,2];", for example.

Comment: Actually, if I try "( (cells[row,1]==1) && (cells[row+1, 1]==2) && (cells[row+2,1]==3) )" it Works, but only if I drop the cubes one by one in the order : CUBE1 -> CUBE2 -> CUBE3 (= you can't drop a cube aside the stack and then complete the stack created before because the "row" number changed (row++) in the for loop). Basically: If I drop a Cube I want to find a way to compare the Cubes by position, not by comparison (row+1, row+2…). It's hard to describe, sorry… Thanks again.